# WSO2 problem during Proxy Service for SOAP to REST transformation

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wso2

I'm new on WSO2 and for a huge project we are using the EI 6.1.1.

One of our goals is to create some REST services that must substitutes some legacy SOAP services: for do that, we are developing Spring Boot REST and our idea is to expose these one in a SOAP way, with same WSDL of the legacy service.

We are creating a Proxy Service on WSO2 and we are able to call the rest service in backend, but, even if the REST logging show us that everything goes fine, the SOAP call never send back response, and "die" with a read timeout.

How can we fix that? I'll post you the proxyService configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="VerificaAmbitiSET_SOAP_AWS"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <filter xmlns:ver="http://XXXXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXX"
                 xpath="//ver:getAmbitiSet">
            <then>
               <property expression="//ver:getAmbitiSet/ver:codiceFiscale"
                         name="REST_URL_POSTFIX"
                         scope="axis2"
                         type="STRING"/>
               <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="GET"/>
            </then>
            <else/>
         </filter>
         <header name="Accept" scope="transport" value="*/*"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address format="rest"
                        uri="http://localhost:8280/services/A_SERVICE/ambitiSet"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL key="conf:/wsdl/A_WSDL.wsdl"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

and this is the REST controller sign:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/ambitiSet/{codiceFiscale}")
    public List<Ambito> getAmbitiSET(@PathVariable("codiceFiscale") String codiceFiscale)
```

Finally, my SOAP request looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ver="http://XXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ver:getAmbitiSet>
         <ver:codiceFiscale>XXZXZXZXZ</ver:codiceFiscale>
      </ver:getAmbitiSet>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Greeting.

Answer (score -1):

You can test where the response is getting dropped via enabling wire logs. Please follow the blog https://medium.com/@tharika/how-to-read-and-understand-wire-logs-in-wso2-products-c384af0b8ea5